# how to get result of CamFind API?

Tags: android, api, android-camera, response

I am using CamFind API for image recognition in my app. I am following [CamFind Tutorial](https://www.mashape.com/imagesearcher/camfind?utm_campaign=embed&utm_medium=button&utm_source=camfind&utm_content=jslink#!documentation)
but stuck at how to get response from that API after posting data? How you got my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
try {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = Unirest
                .post("https://camfind.p.mashape.com/image_requests")
                .header("X-Mashape-Authorization",
                        "A0MYOpCsdfasdgadfadafgdj7vsdfe")
                .field("image_request[locale]", "en_US")
                .field("image_request[image]",
                        new File("your Image path")).asJson();

        String body =  request.getBody().toString(); 
        Log.v("body", body);
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

now the body string contain the json response String with a Token variable inside it
and to get the recognition name do the same again, but remove the `fields` and add the `Token` value after the url
so it will look like this:
`https://camfind.p.mashape.com/image_requests/(Token Vlaue)`

now the body string will contain the `name` value